# Ordering Column Attributes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework in my application,so I have mapped my property objects to database objects. The property objects have been defined using Column attribute.

Now,I want to order them,but I can't find the property in Column Attribute for Order.

I have included System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,but still not getting it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

just use :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Code :

```
 [Column("Name" , Order = 1)]
 public int UserName { get; set; }
```

Notice : cloumn arder by default takes a big number so if you ordered only this column it will be first one in the table unless you ordered another column with a lower order number which is in this case : 0