# Data Migration Code First Table order is alphabetical

Tags: entity-framework, data-migration

The class have properties ordered in the way it makes sense e.g.

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        public Address {get; set;}
        public City {get; set;}
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowStamp { get; set; }
```

After running data migration the table is generated with columns in sorted order. 
The table generated has Id column followed by City and so on. I like to keep the order of the class
Is there any way to avoid reordering columns while data migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an order using Column Attributes (i.e. DataAnnotations), but I will warn you that it can become troublesome to maintain (too troublesome, IMO). Still, here's what it looks like:

```
[Column("Id" , Order = 1)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Check out [Ordering Column Attributes in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303281/ordering-column-attributes-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Thanks. I want the audit columns at the end.